# Which Fairy Tail episode did Lucy do a map of everybody in Fairy Tail?

Tags: fairy-tail

I saw in an AMV that Lucy drew a map of everybody in Fairy Tail, and I think she was doing the map to try and find everybody and bring them back into the guild.

Which *Fairy Tail* episode shows this moment?

Comment: Could you link to the AMV you are talking about, just so that people can see the part you are talking about?

Comment: You're likely referring to immediately after the time skip, after she re-encounters Natsu. I don't remember the episode number, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are talking about [Episode 276: Challenger](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_276), this is after the Fairy Tail Zero arc.

> After the guild has been disbanded, Lucy is still keeping tabs of her guildmates's locations that why she have that map